# Powershell -or on multiple checks

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that is causing an issue. It's doing a simple check to see if the number of characters entered is either 7 or 8. However, even after entering either 7 or 8 characters it doesn't move onto the else statement and displays "invalid number of characters".

If I remove the -or and stick to just one check then it works fine. I can't seem to get it to work when checking with the -or operator. All the examples I've found seem to suggest the code should work fine so can anyone spot what I'm missing?

```
Function number {
$global:change = read-host "Enter a number"
    if ($global:change.length -ne 7 -or $global:change.length -ne 8) {
        write-host $global:change.length
        write-host -foregroundcolor red "Invalid number of characters"
        number
    }
    else {
        write-host "You entered the correct amount of characters"
    }
}

number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to flip your logic a bit to get this working. Based on the logic in your code, one of the cases will always be true. If you change the code to the following, you will get the desired effect.

```
Function number {
    $global:change = read-host "Enter a number"
    if (($global:change.length -eq 7) -or ($global:change.length -eq 8))
    {
        write-host "You entered the correct amount of characters"
    }
    else
    {
        write-host $global:change.length
        write-host -foregroundcolor red "Invalid number of characters"
        number
    }    
}

number
```

This will test whether you enter a value that is either 7 or 8 and loop if another value is entered.

Comment: Beat me to it. The conditions need to be evaluated individually, with bracketed expressions, before they can be tested with -or.

Answer (score 0):

Change the -or in an -and or style the code in this way:

```
Function number {
$global:change = read-host "Enter a number"
    if ($global:change.length -eq 7 -or $global:change.length -eq 8) {
        write-host "You entered the correct amount of characters" 
    }
    else {
        write-host $global:change.length
        write-host -foregroundcolor red "Invalid number of characters"
        number
    }
}

number
```

Comment: The conditions need to be evaluated individually before they can be tested with -or. See Bradon answer